# how to reference a WinForms form in Access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007

how to reference a C# form, function in Access.
I have tried something about this in the Access function in a module

```
Public Function global_variables()

  Name = Forms!Frm_FrmClient.Txt_Name
   Age = Forms!Frm_FrmClient.Txt_Age
  Team = Forms!Frm_FrmClient.Txt_Team

End Function
```

On ButtonCLick in C# WindowsForms I will open an Access report that has as parameter, the values ​​of this function

and that is how I open the database and call the function before you open the report,on the buttonclick in the C# form .

```
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application MSA = new           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
     MSA.Application.Visible = false;
     MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\\dados\\ClientReport.accdb", false);
                    MSA.Application.Run("global_variables");
MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport("Report_Fich",Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewPreview);
```

And I'm getting the following Error :

```
Microsoft Access can not find the referenced form 'Frm_FrmClient'
```

Comment: Isn't there some way to pass those in to the report, instead of trying to reach backwards for them?  I'd be surprised if you can make what you ask for work.

Comment: So you believe it is not possible? have any other suggestions?

Comment: I've never used any of it.  Does `MSA.Application.Run()` accept any parameters?  As in, can you make `global_variables` take data and store it, instead of it trying to read back to the form?  If not...  In theory, you have the `MSA` opening a database, so perhaps you can have storage on the access side for `Name, Age, Team` and let the `Form` code store those.  Alter the form to use those items, then you just open it.